# Embed a file into EXE file in VB6

Tags: vb6, embed, exe

I am trying to make a setup program in VB6 that will install all the files that are required for the program.

I use a CSV file to store data and read it using:

```
file="C:\users\admin\desktop\table.csv"
Open file For Input As fnum
```

However the EXE file cannot be executed on another laptop as I get the error "`file not found`".

So: **how to embed this CSV document into the .EXE file so that the program can run on any Windows PC**?

Comment: There are very good reasons *not to try to do this at all.* For one thing there are many pitfalls in the installation process, and you could screw up other applications if not your own. For another, programs that embed programs are likely to trigger as "droppers" in anti-malware - for good reason. There are perfectly good packaging tools out there already, take a minute to learn one. If you must self-extract use one of the common tools that anti-malware "trusts" already instead of writing something ad-hoc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open the project, *Add-Ins* menu item, open the *Add-In* manager & double click the *VB6 Resource Editor* to load it, close manager.
2. Click *Project* menu item then *Add new Resource File* at the bottom. Enter a file name for it & save it in the directory with your code files.
3. From the *Project Explorer* tree double click *XXX.RES* from the new *Related Documents* node.
4. Select *Add Custom Resource* from the toolbar in the window that pops up
5. Browse to your .csv and add it, you should see it added as *CUSTOM\101*
6. It will now be embedded into the exe at compile time. If the file changes, re-add it to the resource, there is a 64k limit per entry.
7. To load it in code at runtime:

   `strCSV = strconv(LoadResData(101, "CUSTOM"), vbunicode)`

Comment: hi thanks for your post....i added the csv file as custom resource and used it in the program..and it ran like butter. But after making it  as exe, I tried to input value in textbox, then it shows: Runtime error 9, "subscript out of range" ...I think that it might not be storing the values of .csv file, so do you know any solution to this problem?

Comment: The resource is not writeable, if you want to do that then load it, write it to disk and use that copy - if its another issue a new question would be best.

Comment: +1 Here is a link to the [VB6 documentation topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228672(v=vs.60).aspx) about this add-in